# Woocommerce adding icon on a single product gallery image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

I wanted to ask if there is a hook with which I could add icon on a gallery image. I am using storefront theme. Icon container should be located in **woocommerce-product-gallery** wrapper.

This is how it should look like [image]

Comment: Hi, did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please override the **woocommerce/single-product** template file in your activated theme diretory. You can find the code and result in the attached images.

hope this will work for you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not right way, hook is better way to override code.

Comment: I thought about hook which could do that from functions.php but thanks for answer.

Comment: but I didn't find any hook for this. Please check in this link https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below hook:

woocommerce_product_thumbnails, 
with this you can add anything on product image on single pahe for more check below link:

[woocommerce_product_thumbnails](https://therichpost.com/woocommerce-hook-add-icon-on-a-single-product-gallery-image)